# iOS UIWebView crashes when trying to request url

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I got following error,

```
  Assertion failed: (stream != NULL), function cb_spdylay_on_stream_close, file /SourceCache/CFNetwork_Sim/CFNetwork-711.1.12/SPDY/SPDYConnection.cpp, line 1775.
```

when trying to open link using the code,

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad 
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [self.webV loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_FNaB0Xf3wVRVg3UVhaLWpPclU/view"]]];
}
```

this error wasn't happened before 3 days

Comment: any solution for this ? even my application crashes when trying to login into google account . with this error 

    Assertion failed: (stream != NULL),
     function cb_spdylay_on_stream_close, file /SourceCache/CFNetwork_Sim/CFNetwork-711.4.6/SPDY/SPDYConnection.cpp, line 1778.

Comment: no solution until now

Comment: I've done some more research and think that perhaps updating to a WKWebView (rather than a UIWebView) for iOS 8.x+ may fix it.  See my **Edit** below for a link to the documentation.  If you've already tried this, or if you try it and it does/does not work, I'd be very interested.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this issue, too.  I know it doesn't help much, but it looks like it's an iOS 8+ bug when accessing certain servers.

I'm also seeing this when accessing resources from Drive, so maybe they changed something recently?

Information is spotty, but [this is what I'm basing my conclusion on](http://www.openradar.appspot.com/19724022).

**EDIT:**

I haven't had a chance to test this yet, but my current theory is that this problem could be fixed by migrating to using a [WebKit-based view](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/WKWebView) for iOS 8.x+ views.  I'm hoping to get some time to test this theory in the next day or two.  I'll post my results here after that.

**NEW EDIT:**

I just tested opening the same URL with a WKWebView.  The good news is that it didn't crash.  The bad news is that I get an error:

```
Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=300 "WebKit encountered an internal error"
```

Not terribly helpful, Apple.  I'm still researching, but no more luck yet.

Comment: Thank you for your helping , i think the problem from google drive they changed some thing

Comment: Part of me thinks the same thing, too.  The only strange thing is that I can still access the files with the same URL using UIWebView in iOS 7 or through normal Safari in iOS 8.  With the total lack of information about what might be causing it, though, I'm not sure what to do from here.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 solutions for this.

1. Move to WKWebView: for iOS 8+
2. Add Custom UserAgent

Use this sample UserAgent:

> Mozilla/5.0 AppleWebKit/600.5.17 Version/8.0.5 Safari/600.5.17

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Mozilla/5.0 AppleWebKit/600.5.17 Version/8.0.5 Safari/600.5.17", @"UserAgent", nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionary];
```

It's about [Spoofing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/Tasks/Spoofing.html)

> Some websites will deliver different content to different programs that ask for the same page. In extreme cases, a website may deny access completely to some programs. When this happens, you can try to gain access to the site by “spoofing” as another browser.

Check details at my blog: http://trinnguyen.com/cocoa-spdy-issue-fixed-for-webview/

Answer (score 0):

We are getting a crash on iOS 8.x at:

```
    CFNetwork 0x0000000184574058 cb_spdylay_on_stream_close + 192
```

It seems that in iOS 9 Beta 5 and iOS 7.1 it is working perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes just on iOS 8.x , any solution please ?